# YT.Player doesn't return an instance with playVideo()

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

When I create an instance of `YT.Player(HTMLIFrameElement, { options })` I get back an object that has:

- destroy
- setSize
- getIframe
- addEventListener
- getVideoEmbedCode
- getOptions
- getOption

But not `playVideo`, `pauseVideo` etc as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls).

I got a demo here: http://siesta-annotations.surge.sh/Siesta_webviewer_test/?page=3

I am creating the iframes via the DOM in `trait.playable.youtube.js` and adding the iframe to a `documentFragment` that eventually will be added to a div:

```
const element = document.createElement('iframe')
element.src = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}?rel=0;&autoplay=${this.options.autostart ? 1 : 0};&enablejsapi=1;&origin=${location.hostname};`
element.style = this.inlineStyle
```

I then create an instance of YT.Player:

```
// nasty initialization because we're outside webpack and this is a demo
if (global.YT.loaded) {
  this.player = new global.YT.Player(element, {
    events: {
      'onStateChange': this.stateHandler,
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  })
} else {
  const oldHandler = global.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady
  global.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
    if (oldHandler) oldHandler()

    this.player = new global.YT.Player(element, {
      events: {
        'onStateChange': this.stateHandler,
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The instance of YT.Player looks something like this:

[image: YT.Player instance object tree]

It looks like the minification process went very wrong. What am I doing wrong - how should I initialise YT.Player for my use-case?

Comment: I should also add that no event handlers are being called, so there is definitely something wrong in how I create `YT.Player`.

Comment: After looking at how [plyr](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) does it, I can see that the API is not exposed through the instance but via the event.target of `onReady`. I should update this question with a proper answer, when I have time...

Comment: I have the same exact problem in 2021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough you do not get access to the YTPlayer API until `'onReady'` is called in the constructor player options object. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': function (event) {
        onPlayerReady(event.target)
      },
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(player) {
  player.playVideo();
}
```

This of course only works for one player, so you need to roll out your own YouTube player manager if you want to handle multiple players. *(I know the API is insane)*

A quick solution could be the following if you have iframes with youtube videos (*untested*):

```js
const YTManager = {
  videos: [],
  youtubeApiReady = false,
  initialize () {
    const matchId = /[^/]+$/

    this.youtubeApiReady = true
    
    document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="youtube"]')
      .forEach(iframe => this.videos.push({
         dom: iframe,
         player: null,
         videoId: iframe.src.exec(matchId) || iframe.src.exec(matchId)[0]
       }))
  },
  createPlayers () {
    if (this.youtubeApiReady === false) return

    this.videos.forEach(v => {
      new YT.Player(v.dom.id, {
        videoId: v.videoId,
        events: {
          'onReady': function (event) {
            v.player = event.target
          }
        }
      })
    })
  },
  find (id) {
    return this.videos.find(v => v.id === id)
  },
  play (id) {
    const video = this.find(id)
    if (this.youtubeApiReady && video && video.player) {
      video.playVideo()
    }
  },
  pause (id) {
    const video = this.find(id)
    if (this.youtubeApiReady && video && video.player) {
      video.pauseVideo()
    }
  },
}

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  // YouTube client side script has been loaded
  YTManager.youtubeApiReady = true
  YTManager.createPlayers()
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // all iframes has been parsed by the browser
  YTManager.initialize()
});
```

Of course you can not call `YTManager.play` or `YTManager.pause` without having the ID and wait for the YouTube script to load and then the video initialization to finish. All in all, a real mess. I'm sure you can come up with a better manager. I have written one at work that is better but also works with completely different objects and requirements, so it's not a good fit for general purpose YouTube video manager. But the one above is the gist of my current player.

I recommend using iframes from the beginning - if anything goes wrong in your script, the videos will still be playable, you will just not have any control of them.

Iframed youtube videos looks like this:

```html
<iframe
  id="uniqueDOMElementID1"
  width="560"
  height="315"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bHQqvYy5KYo"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my second post, I hope that I can solve your problem.

I am not 100% sure about how your code works, but I suspect ...

> It seems like a double instantiation of the `YT.Player` object, which will cause the `YT.Player` object unstable.

I myself also struggled for a long time (ps: I am an amateur programmer.)

As an example, the following snippets is modifed from [Youtube Iframe API website](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) and an example of how the second instantiation will break the player object [try it! JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/yukixoqapu/edit?html,console,output):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>
    </br>
    <button onclick="instantiateOneMore()">
        Call
        <pre>new YT.Player('player')</pre>
    </button>
    <button onclick="pauseVideo()">
      pauseVideo();
    </button>
    <script>
        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });

        }


        let callTime = 0;
        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
            callTime ++;
            console.log(callTime);
            //document.querySelector('#dd').innerHTML = player.pauseVideo;
        }
      function pauseVideo(){
        player.pauseVideo();
      }
        instantiateOneMore = () => {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            //document.querySelector('#dd').innerHTML = player.pauseVideo;
        }

        // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
        //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
        //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
        var done = false;

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                /* setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000) */
                ;
                done = true;
            }
        }
        /* 
              function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
              } */
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Furthermore, the second `onPlayerReady()`, won't even be called. So if you intend to put some counter to see how many times the `new YT.Player(...)` is called, you  will suspect it only be called once. Which makes the effect ghost away from debugging.

Comment: By the code you have posted here `instantiateOneMore` is never called. You define it with `instantiateOneMore = () => {` as a global function but never call it later. It's global because you do not have a `var` variable declaration in front of `instantiateOneMore`. All `var` variable declarations are in the scope of the function where they are. Since your code is not wrapped in a function, that makes omitting `var` equivalent to use `var`.

Comment: It's passed as a callback for button event. I want to show the problem interactively. It placed it in the JS Bin. (https://jsbin.com/yukixoqapu/4/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old question but I've stumble upon this problem today and resolved by myself although it took me hours.

**In my case the culprit was wrong video id.**

Let's say, the right id is `videoId:"M7lc1UVf-VE"` but I originally entered `videoId:"M7lc1UVf-VE?si=5rdPpwWtXnTEFHd_`. Somehow, it partially worked, the movie was actually playing, but other functions never worked.

So, I recommend checking whether you have unnecessary parameters on the video id.